# C# execute all cases in switch statement

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement, case

I have a switch statement like the following :

```
switch(task)
    {
        case 1:
            print();
            break;
        case 2:
            save();
            break;
        case 3:
            sendmail();
            break;
    }
```

I need a way to execute all cases, which means if task is (All)
I want to print, save and send mail.
Is it doable using some modification on the given case
I know that, I can make it as follow:

```
case All:
    print();
    save();
    sendmail();
    break;
```

But as I said I want to know, if there is a way in switch statement to execute all cases.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a flags enumeration and create a `Dictionary<enum, Action>`. You can use a foreach-loop over all enum values and check whether an entry is available and execute the method. So switch is needed in that case.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as the answer. But when you add complexity to the flow of these conditions - it'll become less readable. Just split it out and make multiple calls to `print()`, for example.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your actual question:

> if there is a way in switch statement to execute all cases.

Not a clean way that I can think of.

---

I would suggest changing the pattern a bit and instead making `task` a [flag enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[Flags]
public enum TaskOptions 
{
    Print    = 1,
    Save     = 2,
    SendMail = 4,
    //Note that these numbers go up in powers of two
}
```

You can then do something like the following:

```
task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save;
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.Print))
{ 
    print();
}
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.Save))
{ 
    save();
}
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.SendMail))
{ 
    sendMail();
}
```

You no longer have to worry explicitly about `all`

---

Then if you wanted to add a new option

```
[Flags]
public enum TaskOptions 
{
    Print    = 1,
    Save     = 2,
    SendMail = 4,
    NewOption = 8,
}

task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save;
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.Print))
{ 
    print();
}
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.Save))
{ 
    save();
}
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.SendMail))
{ 
    sendMail();
}
if (task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.NewOption))
{ 
    newOption();
}
```

---

Jaymee asked for clarification about the `|` and the `&`

> Can you please explain the syntax of task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save. Not sure on the use of the pipe here, I thought it was 'or', but there's no evaluation here!? In fact, same for the single ampersand - never seen it used in that way before

These are **bitwise operators**. They compare two numbers, bit by bit and return a result.

In our example, we're using 4 flags, each represented by a boolean. A boolean can be represented by one bit.

Let's use the following abbreviations:

```
Print = P
Save = S
SendMail = M
NewOption = N

8  4  2  1
N  M  S  P
```

I used `task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save` as an example

```
0  0  0  1   P is declared as 1 in the enum. 
0  0  1  0   S is declared as 2 in the enum.
========== 
0  0  1  1   < I've "or'd" these numbers together. They now represent Print AND Save as one option. The number "3" (binary 0011) is equivalent to "print and save"
```

When I have "3" and I want to know if it contains a specific flag, I `&` with that flag.

```
N  M  S  P
0  0  1  1  //This is P & S
0  0  0  1  //And we want to check if it has "P"
==========
0  0  0  1  < this returns non-zero. it contains the flag!
```

Let's do the same thing for N

```
N  M  S  P
0  0  1  1  //This is P & S
1  0  0  0  //And we want to check if it has "N"
==========
0  0  0  0  < this returns zero. This state doesn't contain "N"
```

**Edit by David Arno**

To add to this answer, rather than having a series of `if`s, a Dictionary and for loop can be used instead:

```
private readonly Dictionary<TaskOptions, Action> actions =
    new Dictionary<TaskOptions, Action>
    {
        { TaskOptions.Print, Print },
        { TaskOptions.Save, Save },
        { TaskOptions.SendMail , SendMail }
    };

...

var task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save;
foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TaskOptions)).Cast<TaskOptions>())
{
    if (task.HasFlag(enumValue))
    {
        actions[enumValue]();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if I have 5 cases :) not 3

Comment: Then just add more cases to the enum: `Option4=8, Option5=16` and repeat the pattern for the `if`s

Comment: would this line be changed [ task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save;]

Comment: Which line do you mean?

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax of `task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save`. Not sure on the use of the pipe here, I thought it was 'or', but there's no evaluation here!? In fact, same for the single ampersand - never seen it used in that way before.

Comment: `task.HasFlag(TaskOptions.NewOption)`

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thanks very much, +1.

Comment: @Backs, I didn't know that was a thing :P

Comment: You could improve this answer by replacing the series of `if`s with a `Dictionary<TaskOptions, Action>`. Aside from that, it's a good answer.

Comment: @DavidArno, I did think of something like that, but I'm a little rusty with C#. Feel free to edit! 

Comment: ok, I can't say anything about this effort, but I am a little bit confused, How can I fire all the cases, what the value of task to match all cases. task = ??

Comment: You can either pipe all Tasks together as in `task = TaskOptions.Print | TaskOptions.Save | TaskOptions.SendMail`or use math: `task = 2^(numofTasks)-1`. In this case, all `bits` are 1 and correspond to all options.

Comment: @Backs, I agree. Feel free to edit. I'm not very protective over the answers I write. Especially for tags I'm not exactly excellent in.

Comment: @JamesWebster @.Sven @.DavidArno thanks a lot, you're so helpful

Comment: but unfortunately, this is not doable using switch, this is what I can figure out from all the answers and comments. :)

Comment: @RMohammed, to be honest, I view `switch` as a code smell. Just about anything that you'd be tempted to use `switch` for can be more neatly implemented with a dictionary of delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Try add a separate class with a special behavior because it is more clear than hacking the `switch` statement:

```
class FallSwitch 
{
     SortedDictionary<int, Action> _cases = new SortedDictionary<int, Action>();

    public void AddCaseAction(int @case, Action action)
    {
        if (_cases.ContainsKey(@case)) throw ArgumentException("case already exists");
        _cases.Add(@case, action);
    }

    public void Execute(int startCase)
    {
        if (!_cases.ContainsKey(startCase)) throw ArgumentException("case doesn't exist");
        var tasks = _cases.Where(pair => pair.Key >= startCase);
        tasks.ForEach(pair => pair.Value());
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var fs = new FallSwitch();
fs.AddCaseAction(0, () => Console.WriteLine("0"));
fs.AddCaseAction(1, () => Console.WriteLine("1"));
fs.AddCaseAction(2, () => Console.WriteLine("2"));
fs.AddCaseAction(6, () => Console.WriteLine("6"));

fs.Execute(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested the comment as answer.

Maybe you should consider using a flags enumeration and create a Dictionary. You can use a foreach-loop over all enum values and check whether an entry is available and execute the method. So switch is needed in that case.

```
[Flags]
public enum TaskOptions 
{
    Print    = 1,
    Save     = 2,
    SendMail = 4
}

// In the clase where print(), save() and sendmail() are declared
private readonly Dictionary<TaskOptions, Action> _tasks;

public Ctor()
{
    _tasks = new Dictionary<TaskOptions, Action>
        {
            { TaskOptions.Print, this.print },
            { TaskOptions.Save, this.save },
            { TaskOptions.SendMail, this.sendmail }
        };
}

public void Do(TaskOptions tasksToRun)
{
    foreach (var action in from taskOption in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TaskOptions)).Cast<TaskOptions>()
                           where tasksToRun.HasFlag(taskOption)
                           orderby taskOption // only to specify it in the declared order
                           select this._tasks[taskOption])
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

But you got already an answer that did the same using a clean strategy pattern. This is more or less the same but using delegates instead of classes.

Comment: Good answer. One small thing though: I'd argue the other answer uses a GoF-style command pattern, not the strategy pattern. I'd dispute "clean" also, as delegates are a much cleaner implementation of both patterns.

Answer (score 0):

As you'll know, in C# fall-through does not happen implicitly but rather `goto` was extended to allow for case labels to be target labels so that fall-through can be explicit.

Simply have your "all" value match the first label, and then continue to `goto` the next if that is the value:

```
switch(task)
{
  case 1: case 0;//I don't know what "all" is, so I'm using 0 here
    print();
    if (task == 0) goto case 2;
    break;
  case 2:
    save();
    if (task == 0) goto case 3;
    break;
  case 3:
    sendmail();
    break;
}
```

Comment: @modiX never use the standard idiom for fall-through in the language? Why? (And please tell me you aren't basing this on something Dijkstra wrote in 1968. This particular use of those four letters did not exist in 1968).

Comment: Indeed, I'm not using `GOTO`, I'm using `goto`…

Comment: @JonHanna - the validity of what Dijkstra said still stands. Controlling the flow with `goto` is horrible.

Comment: the `if task==0` condition in `case 2` will never evaluate true.

Comment: @JayMee why, because those four letters have magical powers? The way `goto case` works in C# has nothing to do with what Dijkstra was writing about.

Comment: @JonHanna - why bring it up then?

Comment: @jaket of course it won't, What's that got to do with anything?

Comment: @JayMee to preempt nonsense arguments based on it.

Comment: Ah I see. That is convoluted. 25 years of programming experience and I missed the subtly of you putting to case statements on a single line leading to missing the fact that task can be 0 in case 2.

Comment: That's a horrible language feature IMO

Comment: @jaket it allows for fallthrough to not be implicit any more, which is a syntactically nice feature, but one that has been shown to be bug-prone in practice. Sometimes a bit of syntactic vinegar can be as useful as syntactic sugar.

Comment: I completely agree with you. In fact I upvoted you given you *literally* answered the question. At the same time I'd normally look for a different solution to this type of problem.

Comment: @jaket I normally do too, but when fall-through does the trick, I'll use fall-through without qualm. I like that it's a bit ugly though; it means the language is favouring the more usual at the aesthetic level :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a more object oriented approach. Define a set of classes each responsible for executing one type of task. When you want to run multiple tasks just queue up the individual tasks. Using the switch statement is terribly inflexible. Imagine someday adding a 4th task and then wanting also an option to run tasks 1,2 & 4 in sequence.

```
 RunTasks(new[] {new PrintTask(), new SaveTask(), new SendMailTask()});

 void RunTasks(int[] tasks)
 {
     foreach (var task in tasks)
     {
         task.Run();
     }
 }

 interface ITask
 {
     void Run();
 }

 class PrintTask : ITask
 {
      public void Run()
      {
          ....
      }
  }

  // etc...
```

Comment: You are re-inventing the command-pattern wheel here. C# already has `Action` which more neatly covers the pattern, without having to create loads of highly repetitive classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new case like so

```
switch(task)
{
    case 1:
        print();
        break;
    case 2:
        save();
        break;
    case 3:
        sendmail();
        break;
    case 4:
        print();
        save();
        sendmail();
        break;
}
```

Alternatively you could set the default case to execute all cases

```
 switch(task)
{
    case 1:
        print();
        break;
    case 2:
        save();
        break;
    case 3:
        sendmail();
        break;
    default:
        print();
        save();
        sendmail();
        break;
}
```

Neither of these ways are very neat, I think they're probably the most simple solution to your problem though.